# Bar Colouring in jqplot

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I am attempting to use jqplot to draw a stacked bar chart with the top series being filled in white with a green outline. Is this possible with normal options, or will I have to to it via CSS? The following code is what I am currently using. I've basically tried throwing every color based option at it (I'm confused by the docs, I admit). I was expecting, for the second series, an outline of colour "color" and a fill of colour "fillColor" (i.e. blue and red respectively), but this is not what is happening. Can anyone help?

```
//Bar Chart
var pots = ['Seats', 'Shoes', 'Refurb', '4 FatC2s', 'Lightweight Four'];
var moneyInPots = [50, 200, 300, 400, 600];
var moneyRemaining = [70, 300, 700, 500, 1900];
plot1 = $.jqplot('potGraph', [moneyInPots, moneyRemaining],
          { 
            stackSeries: true,
            seriesDefaults: 
            {
              renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
              pointLabels: {show: true}
    },
            axes: 
            {
              xaxis:
              {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                ticks: pots
              },
      yaxis:
              {
                min: 0,
                tickOptions: {formatString: '&pound;%d'}
              }
    },

    series:
            [
              {color: 'green', shadow: false},
              {color: 'blue', fill: true, fillColor: 'red', fillAndStroke: true, shadow: false, fillToZero: true, fillAxis: 'y'}
            ]

          });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, fillAndStroke cannot be used to draw an outline around a bar. This option is used exclusively when you want to add a stroked line to a filled line plot. You can refer to the filledLine.html example available in your JQPlot package.

I do not think there is a way to add an outline around a bar, either through one of the JQPlot options or using CSS.